# Filehandle stored in hash variable reading as GLOB

Tags: perl, file

Perl version 5.22

When I try to do a simple output like this, it works. File outputs fine, can continue:

```
open my $IN, '<', 'somefile.txt' or die ('Failed to open');
while (my $line = <$IN>) {
  chomp $line;
  print $line;
}
close ($IN);
```

The following, however, does not work:

```
my %filehandles;
open $filehandles{'IN'}, '<', 'somefile.txt' or die ('Failed to open');
while (my $line = <$filehandles{'IN'}>) {
  chomp $line;
  print $line;
}
close ($filehandles{'IN'});
```

When `$line` is printed in the second example, it only outputs something like GLOB(0x...), which I assume is just the type. **In the second example, I don't want the GLOB, but the file contents.**

I want to use the hash approach because my code might need to open a variable number of file handlers, and I should be able to close them all cleanly at the end of the function. So is there something small that I'm missing?